# How to correctly provide networking feedback to the user?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, networking, nsurlconnection

My app retrieves currency exchange rates from a web service using a synchronous NSURLConnection in a background GCD queue, like this:

```
// This method is called in background queue
- (NSData*)fetchDataWithURLStr:(NSString*)urlStr {
    NSData *jsonData = nil;

   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
    NSURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    jsonData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    if (error != nil) {
        NSString *errorMsg = nil;
            NSInteger ec = [error code];

        if (ec == NSURLErrorTimedOut || ec == NSURLErrorCannotConnectToHost) {
            errorMsg = @"Data temporarily not available.";
        }


        // Call on main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Present the error
            [self showErrorWithCode:ec title:@"ERROR" message:errorMsg];
        });


        jsonData = nil;
    }

    return jsonData;
}
```

But the problem is often the app tries to fetch data, and the download seems to be running forever and nothing happens. No status updates just nothing. Often my WiFi is just stalled and I must go to Settings, disable and re-enable this. Or internet connectivity of my WiFi router at home is down but the device is connected to WiFi.

What I really want to do is give precise feedback about what exactly is happening on the network right now. For example

"Trying to contact server..."
"Wait... still trying..."
"Your internet seems broken..."
"Trying again..."
"Response received..."
"Downloaded 20%"
"Downloaded 40%"
"Finished!"

Just exact feedback about what is going on.

Someone recommended MKNetworkKit but it just feels as dead, no feedback whatsoever.

Are there solutions to this problem which work for iOS?

EDIT: I have Reachability in place but it does not give me this kind of feedback I want to display during networking. Also, Reachability does not tell me what is going on when there is a WiFi connection but the internet is stalled.

Comment: why a synchronous connection when we can have an async connection for the same.. and you are notified on each append or completion...

Comment: Not sure what you mean, @Apple_iOS0304. There are things I want to do when the download completed, so it blocks a background thread which is exactly what I want. Or does the async NSURLConnection have other advantages beyond being async?

Comment: ok i get it.. yes reachability certainly does not give precise information about everything.. sorry for the rush into the answering.. i apologize for that. but if u check for netRechable and hostRechable wouldn't it help you on your wifi issue.. i haven't tried it, but im just curious to know dat.

Comment: Yes I checked those, but they only tell me that WiFi is disabled or not connected. However, when the device is connected over WiFi, or has reception + internet (e.g. 3G) then nothing will happen. Internet stalled and no message, nothing.

Comment: is there something or someway to ping the router/wifi as we have an ip for that such as: 192.168.1.1... is there a way to do that? bcoz if there is a way like this, you would achieve ur desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental problem here is that it is impossible (yes **impossible**) to give a reliable diagnosis of a network problem based on the information that is available to your app.  There are simply too many possible causes, and some of them are simply not distinguishable without knowledge of the actual networks and / or access to other sources of diagnostic information.

Answer (score 0):

U can user Reachability classes.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324) is a sample code which uses this reachability classes, and notifies us which type connection we are using. The sample code is from apple.

Have a look at & implement in the same way.

In order for showing the progress to the user, i suggest to use `NSURLConnection` from the its delegate methods you can easily get the status of the connection/request.

In one of its delegate it gives error description.

Comment: Updated the question. I use Reachability but it would only tell me that for example Airplane mode is on. But not so granular feedback about the particular download attempts.

Comment: NSURLConnection delegate won't tell me anything when the internet is stalled right? Stalled internet is what happens often, only way to fix it is renew DHCP lease in WiFi settings or toggle WiFi on/off but there must be a mechanism to detect it is stalled other than waiting 10 minutes and trying again.

Comment: have u tried `NSURLConnection` in the `connectionFailure` delegate what error it showed, this is called when connection is not established for an interval.. and also we have a delegate for number bytes uploaded or downloaded, u can use to show the progress.. & for the speed u can compare with the previous/received bytes..

Answer (score 0):

You should use the **asynchronous** API instead. Using the synchronous API in a separate worker thread/queue is often not the right way to go (see the WWDC'12 videos about those subjects)

A better solution would be to use the newer `NSURLConnection` API and the `+sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` method instead of using `sendSynchronousRequest: returningResponse: error:`. This way you would avoid blocking your API and be informed when the request fails (either fails starting or fails while running because the network went down etc).

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse*, NSData*, NSError*) {
     // Code that will be executed asynchronously
     // when the response to the request has been received 
 }];
// After the call to this method above, the code will continue executing
// WITHOUT WAITING for the network request to have its response.
```

This way your UI won't "freeze" and the rest of your code will continue to run, so you can, like, show some progress indicator on your views for example, and so on. The code in the `completionHandler` block will be called asynchronously (independently of the rest of your code) only once the response has arrived.

Moreover, to be informed when the network itself is unreachable (went down, etc), use Reachability for that [EDIT] You seem to do this already as you added in the EDIT of your question, so you should already be informed about that and being able to inform the user in this case)

---

Tip: you may also use some third party frameworks, like the excellent [`AFNetworking`(https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking), that allows you to do much more when sending network requests, like having an Objective-C block of code to be called while the network request is in progress, allowing you to know the progression of the download easily.

Once you have integrated the `AFNetworking` project in your workspace, you would be able to do stuff like this:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation* reqOp = [[[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request] autorelease];
[reqOp setCompletionBlockWithSuccess: ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
 {
    // Code to execute asynchronously when you successfully received the whole page/file requested
    // The received data is accessible in the responseObject variable.
 } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    // Code to execute asynchronously when you request failed, for example if you have a network error, or received some 404 error code, etc.
    progressLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Download error: %@", error];
 }];
[reqOp setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead)
 {
    // Code to execute periodically each time a partial chunk of data is received
    // So that you can update your progression. For example:
    progressLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Downloading %.1f%%", (float)totalBytesRead*100.f/totalBytesExpectedToRead];
 }];
[reqOp start]; // start the request
// The rest of the code will continue to execute, and the blocks mentioned above will be called asynchronously when necessary.
```

Comment: You're mostly right, but in this case I have a good reason for using this exact same serial queue with a blocking networking connection. It's a background queue which totally depends on the download to complete before proceeding, therefore using a synchronous call in the background is exactly right. NSURLConnection won't give feedback regarding stalled internet either.

Comment: Well, I read that you used a background GCD queue, but as explained this is not the best approach anyway for me, as using blocks to signal the end of the network operation, and writing the code to execute upon completion in that block is more efficient that using a worker thread dedicated to the download. Also read my edit that explains how to do this using blocks, and how to be informed about the progression of the download too (which was your original question by the way).

Comment: This answer is more about "How to create asynchronous network requests" than dealing with stalled internet / unreachability / networking feedback. Like I outlined in the question, the main problem is to give feedback in cases the download does not start for whatever reason, such as stalled internet and other problems. A progress bar is nice but only helps if the download actually started. In this case (just a small currency exchange rates JSON) the download finishes instantly once it began, so a progress bar is pointless.

Comment: Yes but you edited your question since my answer ;) If you use Reachability (as you finally added in your edit), it should warn you about network reachability issues. (And again, my answer also explains how to handle network errors using `AFNetworking` -- that does a much better work that `NSURLConnection` in addition to track the download progression)

Comment: In another context your answer would be excellent though. Just want to make sure others on SO don't misinterpret your answer as "the" answer, because my question is still far from answered.

Comment: Ah, I see. But I don't see where AFNetworking handles network errors? The method above only provides download progress (bytes read, bytes expected, etc) to show a progress bar. How about precise messages like "Trying to resolve DNS", "sending ping to foo bar", "internet seems stalled, toggle WiFi on/off", etc. Reachability doesn't help in any way, tried everything. All it warns is when internet is really turned off.

Comment: I also gave an example using the `setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:failure:` method of `AFNetworking`, that handles network errors. But I guess your question was not specific enough the first time, I though you were interesting in the standard network errors, reachability, and download progress as application usually do. I am pretty sure anyway that you can't be informed about so low-level stuff like resolving DNS and sending pings to the server, as this is low-level and managed by the CFNetwork core component (which does not expose those stuff) above which every other API is based.

Comment: And the same is for "the internet seems stalled", as there is no such detectable thing. You can only "guess" that the internet connection "seems stalled" if you realize that your download progression is very slow or that your request hasn't received any data since a long time, and even that does not really mean anything as you may have other apps that download stuff in the background (like an AppStore update for example) that could otherwise explain the slow download speed. All you can do is wait for the timeout, or guess it yourself using the progress block of your `AFHTTPRequestOperation`.

Comment: Proud Member: I think we'll all know it's not "the" answer if it's not accepted and especially if it's not even upvoted. No need to downvote it just for being not exactly what you're looking for...

Answer (score -1):

Here is how i check for internet connection . You need to add the Reachability first .

```
+ (BOOL) checkNetworkStatus
{
   Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
   NetworkStatus networkStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
   return !(networkStatus == NotReachable);
}
```